# semantic-ui dropdown's onChange not firing

Tags: jquery, django, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic-ui along with Django and I have the following dropdown in a form:

**HTML**

```
<form id="lang_form" action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}
  {% get_available_languages as LANGUAGES %}
  {% get_language_info_list for LANGUAGES as languages %}
  <input id="lang_input" name="language" type="hidden">
  <div id="lang_dropdown" class="ui icon dropdown button ">
    <span class="text"></span>
    <div class="menu">
      {% for language in languages %}
        <div class="item" data-value="{{language.code}}">
          <i class="{{language.code|flag_class}} flag"></i>
        </div>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

What I'm trying to do is set the value of the dropdown via jquery initially and after that attach a function to the onChange event.

**jquery**

```
$("#lang_dropdown").dropdown('set selected', "{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}");

var flagChange = function(value, text, $choice){
    value = $("#lang_dropdown").dropdown('get value');
    if(value != "{{LANGUAGE_CODE}}"){
      $("#lang_input").val(value);
      $("#lang_form").submit();
    }
};
$("#lang_dropdown").dropdown({
  onChange: flagChange
});
```

What's happening is *flagChange* fires when the dropbox is initially set, which is not my main problem, although the reason it fires despite having  been attached to onChange **AFTER** the initial assignment escapes me.

The main problem is *flagChange* is not firing thereafter whenever I click the dropdown and change the selected value.

Comment: Can you try to use a hidden input inside your `#lang_dropdown` which can hold selected value?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out this issue: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/3744

Looks like there is a bug when adding onChange handlers after the initial dropdown creation. Try adding the change handler during the initial creation.

Comment: Your link seems to be broken.

Comment: That feeling when you google for this issue, and it turns out I was the one that made the issue on their tracker.... :/

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `<select>` `<option>` version of the dropdown : http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#converting-form-elements.

I don't know how Semantic-UI deals with the event, but imho the 'change' event is a basic html/js one and triggers only on that kind of elements.